# html 5 validation error with content element

Tags: html, validation

For some reason, I get the following error when attempting to validate my code

Line 36, Column 10: Element content not allowed as child of element article in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Can anyone help, can this be corrected?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Pete Webpage</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
        </head>

    <body class ="body"> <!-- body start -->

        <header class="mainheader">
         <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
        <nav><ul>
            <li> <a href="url">link text</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="url">link text</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="url">link text</a> </li>  
            <li> <a href="url">link text</a> </li>  
        </ul></nav>
        </header>

        <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">


        <article class="topcontent">
        <header>
        <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First Post</a></h2>  
        </header>

        <footer>
        <p> Pete Webpage</p>
        </footer>

        <content>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus, velit vitae pharetra commodo, erat dui commodo lectus, id fringilla lectus odio et lorem. Curabitur eget tincidunt sapien. Curabitur elementum dolor </p>
        </content>
        </article>
        </div>
        </div>


        <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
        <h2>Top Side bar</h2>
        <p> lacus. Vestibulum nec placerat mauris. Nunc aliquet nisl a gravida egestas. Nam eu ultricies ex. Suspendisse</p>
        </article>  
        </aside>


        <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
        <article>
        <h2>Bottom Side bar</h2>
        <p> lacus. Vestibulum nec placerat mauris. Nunc aliquet nisl a gravida egestas. Nam eu ultricies ex. Suspendisse</p>
        </article>  
        </aside>

        <footer class="mainFooter">
        <p>Copyright this is the footer</p>
        </footer>

        </body>
        </html>
```

many thanks,
Pete

Comment: I'm not able to find the `content` tag on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/, could it be that?

Answer (score 0):

The `<content>` element was proposed for HTML5 but [then rejected before it ever got into standards](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Aug/0298.html).

The validator is therefore correct in not evaluating any of its contents, as it knows not what could or should be in there.

You are probably confused with the [`<main>` element which did get standardized](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/).